# Using pcolormesh for plotting an orbit data

Tags: python, raw-data, satellite-image, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to map a dataset with associated latitude and longitude. The details of the data I am using are given below:

```
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
lat    ndarray    1826x960, type `float64`
lon    ndarray    1826x960, type `float64`
data   ndarray    1826x960, type `float64`
```

I have created then a basemap:

```
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, llcrnrlat=-40, urcrnrlat=40, resolution='c')
```

Now, on the basemap created, I'd plot the above mentioned dataset using pcolormesh:

```
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries
x,y = m(lon,lat)
m.pcolormesh(x,y,data)
m.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This gives following figure:
[Temp Brightness plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5LNF.png)

But if I perform similar plot on a dataset (size 2691x960, same goes to lon and lat) covering whole londitude stretch(-180 to 180), I get a 'strange bar':
[strange bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj47g.png)

I am pretty sure that the strange bar occurs due to the overlapping of dataset. The same plot has been performed in matlab and it works pretty fine.

Please tell me what the problem is, what can be done to remove the bar, what are the other methods of plotting this kind of data in python.

Comment: Just a quick question.  I assume you are using TRMM data.  Does the dataset that you are feeding to pcolormesh extend across the -180/180 boundary?

Comment: I am using MADRAS data, a payload  flew in MEGHATROPICS (INDIA)
Yes I am feeding to pcolormesh extend across the -180/180 boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are running into a problem that I ran into a little bit ago.  The problem here is that, when basemap tries to create the polygons, it uses an interpolation method that does not appear to handle the prime meridian correctly.  Pixels that actually cross the prime maridian get interpolated into a polygon that extends around the globe.

The solution that I have used is to split the file into two masked arrays (or just mask the original array two different ways at different times), one with the eastern hemisphere masked, and one with the western hemisphere masked, then map them both to the same axes object.

edit:  Another solution may be to have your longitude bounds go from -179.99 to 179.99 or something similar.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the basemap but pcolormesh because I have performed the plot without basemap (m here)

`plt.pcolormesh(x,y,data)`

It gives the same result.
I will try masking the conflicting data regions. If it works, I  will inform. 

Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah, you are exactly right.  The issue isn't with basemap, it is with plt.pcolormesh.  I misstated there.

Comment: pcolormesh does not create "polygons" - it is a single block of irregularly shaped, *contiguous* data. Unfortunately, because you are crossing the dateline, you are breaking the contiguous condition. The best solution I know of for this problem is to use cartopy's pcolormesh instead (I will post an answer in the next couple of days to this tune). Please note: cartopy has not yet been announced and is still work in progress.

Comment: @pelson I installed `cartopy` and tried to run the equivalent code, which unfortunately resulted in the same problem ☹.

Comment: Ugh, now that is disappointing...  Hopefully pelson will reply to this and show how to do it with `cartopy`.  I haven't had a chance to work on this yet.

Comment: As the cartopy solution has not materialised in this thread after nearly five years, I have asked it as [a seperate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46527456/974555) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with anything to give me this problem, but it looks like a solution to a similar sounding problem was offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18320385/943773) using the [mpl_toolkit.basemap.addcyclic](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.addcyclic) method.

From the docs:

`arrout, lonsout = addcyclic(arrin, lonsin)` adds cyclic (wraparound) point in longitude to `arrin` and `lonsin`, assumes longitude is the right-most dimension of `arrin`.

Comment: The problem may sound similar, but it is not the same.  `addcyclic` does not work with the dimensions as posed in the question, as it expects a 1-dimensional array for longitudes.