# Preventing plot joining when values "wrap" in matplotlib plots

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting [right ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) [ephemerides](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/index.html) for planets, which have the property that they are cyclical: they hit a maximum value, 24, and then start again at 0. When I plot these using matplotlib, the "jump" from 24 to zero is joined so that I get horizontal lines running across my figure:

[image]

How can I eliminate these lines? Is there an approach in matplotlib, or perhaps a way to split the lists at between the points where the jump occurs.

---

Code to generate above figure:

```
from __future__ import division

import ephem
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot
import math

fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()

ax.set(xlim=[0, 24])
ax.set(ylim=[min(date_range), max(date_range)])

ax.plot([12*ep.ra/math.pi for ep in [ephem.Jupiter(base_date + d) for d in date_range]], date_range,
        ls='-', color='g', lw=2)
ax.plot([12*ep.ra/math.pi for ep in [ephem.Venus(base_date + d) for d in date_range]], date_range,
        ls='-', color='r', lw=1)
ax.plot([12*ep.ra/math.pi for ep in [ephem.Sun(base_date + d) for d in date_range]], date_range,
        ls='-', color='y', lw=3)
```

Comment: FWIW, this same question came up when I worked on a [*Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11714/37) version, and the figures there illustrate the form of the desired result.

Comment: For Python fans, I'm reimplementing a figure I've struggled for *years* to maintain in *Mathematica*: terrible (and astonishingly slow) ephemerides, vexing version incompatibilities, ugly and unreadable code — I think I'll switch to Python for everything!

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46547310/974555
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46548044/974555
https://stackoverflow.com/q/12317155/974555
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46527456/974555

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a generator function that finds the contiguous regions of 'wrapped' data:

```
import numpy as np

def unlink_wrap(dat, lims=[-np.pi, np.pi], thresh = 0.95):
    """
    Iterate over contiguous regions of `dat` (i.e. where it does not
    jump from near one limit to the other).

    This function returns an iterator object that yields slice
    objects, which index the contiguous portions of `dat`.

    This function implicitly assumes that all points in `dat` fall
    within `lims`.

    """
    jump = np.nonzero(np.abs(np.diff(dat)) > ((lims[1] - lims[0]) * thresh))[0]
    lasti = 0
    for ind in jump:
        yield slice(lasti, ind + 1)
        lasti = ind + 1
    yield slice(lasti, len(dat))
```

An example usage would be,

```
x = np.arange(0, 100, .1)
y = x.copy()

lims = [0, 24]

x = (x % lims[1])

fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()

for slc in unlink_wrap(x, lims):
    ax.plot(x[slc], y[slc], 'b-', linewidth=2)

ax.plot(x, y, 'r-', zorder=-10)
ax.set_xlim(lims)
```

Which gives the figure below. Note that the blue lines (which utilize `unlink_wrap`) are broken and the *standard-plotted* red lines are shown for reference.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how this magic works? It's *exactly* the kind of Pythonic solution I was hoping for.

Comment: However, there's one problem: for "shallow" lines (that is, those, such as the [ephemerides for the Moon](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11754/37), where x-values change rapidly, [I get gaps](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sKp11.png) between the boundaries of the figure and the break in the line: the line should *always* run to the end of the figure, so that it is necessary to duplicate the point on the "other side" of the break, extended beyond the limits, at the ends of each sublist. How can the splitting generator be modified to do that?

Comment: FWIW, [here's what I came up with](https://gist.github.com/orome/b4e5fd8a260a94820327). I'm not sure how Pythonic it is, and would appreciate suggestions on improvement.

Comment: Your implementation is excellent! Great work. I made a couple comments on your gist, and also created two gists from yours. [1](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/d04ed05ad9059e94ca01) and [2](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/72a7274fe7b0a064b333).

Comment: Documenting the padding at the ends has created a documentation challenge, and [a follow up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1040185/12400).

Comment: I'm not enough of a math guru to answer (or even understand) your follow-up, but my advice is: 'don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good'. For anyone who needs this function I'm guessing that saying something like 'for each segment endpoints are appended beyond *lims* to be consistent with the points in adjacent segments'... or something like that.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, refactoring a bit made the whole thing a lot clearer.