# Plotting a wrapped path in Basemap

Tags: python, plot, maps, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a satellite ground track. I have a list of latitudes and longitudes in degrees. The longitude values are all from -180 to +180 deg. My first issue is with using the `latlon` keyword (by the way, I'm using this in Julia via the `PyCall.jl` package, so forgive the weird-looking syntax):

```
map = Basemap.Basemap(projection="mill",lon_0=0)
map[:drawcoastlines]()
map[:drawparallels](-90:30:90,labels=[1,0,0,0])
map[:drawmeridians](map[:lonmin]:60:map[:lonmax]+30,labels=[0,0,0,1])
map[:plot](lon,lat,color="red",latlon=true)
```

[image: Weird plot]

This is... not what that should look like. I'm not really sure what the problem is. However, if I convert to map coordinates first:

```
xx,yy = map(lon,lat) 
map[:plot](xx,yy,color="red")
```

[image: Better plot]

This is much better, *except* for the line at the point that the longitude wraps from +180 to -180. Any suggestions for making this look nicer?

The latitude, longitude pairs (in degrees) used for generating these plots can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/UwnwCgFe).

Comment: Any chance that simply re-ordering the list of lat-longs to start and end at the edges of your map would work? In other words, re-order based on longitudes from -180 to 180.

Comment: I tried re-ordering, but because of the overlap over the Pacific, the path bounces back and forth between the upper part and the lower part.

Comment: A solution like this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27139390/3651127

Comment: I was under the impression that basemap is meant to internally handle things like this, so I'm hoping to avoid a homegrown solution.

Comment: can you post your lat lon data somewhere so that people can mess around with it to try and come up with a solution?

Comment: @dagrha see the edit I just made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the beginning I thought this could be related to an [old issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/54) of `Basemap`. However, I think your problem is not due to `Basemap`, which is actually handling correctly the longitude wrapping, as you could see if you used only markers to plot the satellite ground track.

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

f = plt.figure(figsize(10,7.5))
m = Basemap(projection="mill", lon_0=0)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,91,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,181,60), labels=[0,0,0,1])

x,y = m(lon, lat)
m.plot(x, y, color="red", latlon=False, marker='.', linestyle='None')
```

[image]

The definitive solutions would be to split your ground track in multiple tracks and plot them using `LineCollection`, as also explained [here](http://pythology.blogspot.it/2014/02/how-to-avoid-jumping-line-plots-in.html). A simpler approach (if you expect one discontinuity in the longitude):

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

latlon_ar = np.array(latlon)

threshold = 90
idx_wrap = np.nonzero(np.abs(np.diff(latlon_ar[:,1])) > threshold)[0]+1

lon_1 = lon[:idx_wrap]
lat_1 = lat[:idx_wrap]

lon_2 = lon[idx_wrap:]
lat_2 = lat[idx_wrap:]

f = plt.figure(figsize(10,7.5))
m = Basemap(projection="mill", lon_0=0)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,91,30),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,181,60), labels=[0,0,0,1])

x1, y1 = m(lon_1, lat_1)
x2, y2 = m(lon_2, lat_2)

m.plot(x1, y1, color="red", latlon=False)
m.plot(x2, y2, color="blue", latlon=False)
```

[image]

**Edit** This [confirmed bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3404) in `Basemap` is responsible for the behaviour in the first example of the question, where `Basemap.plot` is called directly with latitude and longitude values, having set the `latlon` flag to `True`. There is a [solution](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3404/#issuecomment-53292133), that is to manually shift the input coordinates before plotting, as in the following code.

```python
lons, lats = m.shiftdata(lon, lat)
m.plot(lons, lats, color="blue", latlon=True, marker='.', linestyle='None')
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. Do you have any idea what's going on in my first example (with `latlon=true`)?

Comment: @Chris That _is_ a `Basemap` [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3404). I have updated the answer with the reference to the bug and a possible solution.